# How to load widget grid columns dynamically on extJS grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a grid, In that grid when I expand the row, there is another set of data to be displayed. I want those  grid column to be dynamic. Based on my json data I want to push data in to column. But here When I am giving method, the debugger is not going there. Can anybody explain how to load dynamic column in extJS widget column.

Here is my code

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.base.grid.Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.win',
    title: 'my window',
    height: 500,
    width: 800,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Col 1',
            dataIndex: 'col1',
            flex: 1,
        },{
            text: 'col2',
            dataIndex: 'col2',
            flex: 1
        }],
    }],
   plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowwidget',
        widget: {
            xtype: 'grid',
            columns:[]//this.createColumn() // This columns i want to load dynamically.
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add columns dynamically to the plugin, You have to push the columns config in your plugins column array.

```
grid.getPlugin().config.widget.columns.push({
     text      : 'Item',
     dataIndex : 'item',
     flex      : 1
}, {
     text      : 'Description',
     dataIndex : 'desc',
     flex      : 2
});
```

Created a fiddle for you [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vai)